# Emacs crashes with SWI-prolog

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to run emacs with SWI-prolog on a mac, using the "emacs." command.
However when i do this it instantly crashes before i have any chance at reading the error message being displayed on SWI-Prolog.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This question refers to [`PceEmacs`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/PceEmacs.html), which is the GNU Emacs **clone** that ships with SWI-Prolog, implemented in Prolog using the `XPCE` toolkit. I have removed the `emacs` tag, since that refers to **GNU** Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem. I'm not sure why PceEmacs was crashing whenever I tried to open files in SWI-Prolog, but reinstalling following the instructions here...

http://web.mit.edu/6.863/src/pl-5.6.54/man/macosx/macosx.html#sec:2

...helped. Alternately, you can just write your programs in another text editor and load them in SWI-Prolog with the command...

['/path/filename.pl'].

Doing that works the same.